# Using VS Code to compile c files

Tags: visual-studio-code

So, I just installed the new User Installer version of VS code and I encountererd this problem as I tried to compile my first c program on it and I received this error message
`cannot open source file "stdio.h". Please run the 'Select IntelliSense Configuration...' command to locate your system headers.` and this `stdio.h: No such file or directory`.

I installed the C/C++ extension for VS Code and I expected the problem to be resolved after doing that, but it persisted!